# Принципы дизайна NoSql базы

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Нужно задизайнить небольшую базу в MongoDB, но так как всегда работал только с SQL хочу посоветоваться, прежде чем наколхозить ерунды. Буду очень признателен за советы.

Логика описываемая базой заключается в следующем. Есть удаленная машина(`Vds`) на ней одновременно работает несколько экземпляров приложения(`Thread`). Работа каждого экземпляра разделена на временные смены(`Shift`). А каждая смена имеет несколько прикрепленных аккаунтов(`Account`), каждый из которых, имеет свою историю баланса(`History`).

Вот примерно такая база, если в лоб это описывать:

```
Vds(id: string, ip: string)

Thread(id: string, vdsId: string, num: number)

Shift(id: string, threadId: string, num: number)

Account(id: string, shiftId:string, surviceType: string)

History(id: string, accountId: string, date, balance: number)
```

Затруднение вызвало то, что запросы в таблицу истории могут поступать с любым интервалом, в то время как храить небходимо результирующий баланс за каждый час. Тоесть по результатам работы за сутки, аккаунт может иметь не более 24 записей в истории.

Вопрос в том, есть ли смысл заводить словарь или обойтись логикой на back-end? Или может быть хранить историю прямо внутри `Account` а от `History` вообще отказаться?

Так же вызывает сомнения необходимости объектов `Thread` и `Shift` может все таки проще держать это в `Account`?

Или есть еще какой-то вариант, который подходит лучше, но я его не вижу. Убежден что задача не оригинальна, подскажите как это можно решить.

Самые высокочастотные запросы в порядке убывания:

1. Обновление/добавление баланса по `accountId`. Если в этот час уже что-то приходило то обновляем а если нет, то добавляем запись.
2. Получение истории баланса за последние сутки по `accountId`.
3. Получение даты последнего обновления баланса по `accountId`.

Работать с базой нужно будет через `mongoose`.

Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется, на Ваш вопрос нет однозначного ответа. Прелесть, и в то же время беда, NoSql-баз в том, что Вы можете их проектировать так, как Вам будет удобнее. А понятие удобства, будет зависеть от Ваших навыков работы с ней. Как мне видится, то нужно брать какую-то основу базы (тестовую) и писать код под нее. И в ходе написания уже будет  понятно что удобно, а что нет.

Comment: @Дмытрык ок спасибо. Ваш ответ вполне однозначый на мой взгляд, просто не единственно возвожный.